# Converting a string to specific date format and of date type

Tags: java, date, datetime

I need to convert a string ( 20-04-2014) to date in the format DD-MM-YYYY of type date.

String date = "20-04-2014";

I need to convert it to a type Date. How to do this??

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class like this.

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    String dateString = "20-04-2014";
    Date date = formatter.parse(dateString );
```

[look here for sample](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-string-to-date-java/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **SimpleDateFormat** to implement.

Refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

```
    String date = "20-04-2014";

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Date d = sdf.parse(date);
```